# Post custom object from Android client to JAX-RS

Tags: java, android, jax-rs

I have a simple android client with following code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.11:8080/MyWeb/Test/tests/save");
httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(new Gson().toJson(new Hank()), HTTP.UTF_8));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
System.out.println(responseBody);
```

The goal is to trigger a response from the JAX-RS resource on the server. Here is the server code:

```
@Path("/save")
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Hank saveHank(Hank hank) throws JSONException {      
    System.out.println(hank);
    return hank;
}
```

The responseBody is a HTML-page with the information that the resource is not available. What is wrong?

Comment: "the resource is not available" = your url is most likely wrong (Path or Method actually but that looks ok). Are you sure it's `/MyWeb/Test/tests/` that goes before `/save`?